# Is it possible to write good and understandable code without any comments?

Tags: comments

Can any one suggest what is the best way to write good code that is understandable without a single line of comments?

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209015/self-documenting-code

Comment: Do you mean small comments in the body of functions as opposed to function and class documentation a la javadoc?

Answer (score 19):

I once had a professor when I was in college tell me that any good code should never need any comments.

Her approach was a combination of very precise logic split out into small functions with very descriptive method/property/variable names. The majority of what she presented was, in fact, extremely readable with no comments. I try to do the same with everything I write...

Comment: I wish more of my professors were like that. Most of mine were comment crazy. I remember one requiring a large formatted comment section at the beginning of each source file, a minimum of a four line formatted comment section before each function and every line in the function had to have an inline comment as well. My fingers ached after each assignment.

Comment: @Kenneth And that's where we get stuff like i++; // Add 1 to i and store the result in i.

Answer (score 16):

Read [Code Complete, 2nd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735619670) cover to cover. Perhaps twice.

To give some specifics:

- Making code readable
- Eliminating code repetition
- Doing design/architecture before you write code

Comment: good advice. But maybe provide some of the key concepts that the book will discuss in relation to @pang's question?

Answer (score 9):

I like to 'humanise' code, so instead of:

```
if (starColour.red > 200 && starColour.blue > 200 && starColour.green > 200){
   doSomething();
}
```

I'll do this:

```
bool starIsBright;
starIsBright = (starColour.red > 200 && starColour.blue > 200 && starColour.green > 200);

if(starIsBright){
   doSomething();
}
```

Comment: Sometimes, especially after struggling with cantankerous APIs, I also like to express my feelings by naming functions like `pleaseDoSomething()` :)

Answer (score 7):

In some cases - yes, but in many cases no. The **Yes** part is already answered by others - keep it simple, write it nicely, give it readable names, etc. The **No** part goes to when the problem you solve in code is not a code problem at all but rather domain specific problem or business logic problem. I've got no problem reading lousy code even if it doesn't have comments. It's annoying, but doable. But it's practically impossible to read some code without understanding why is it like this and what is it trying to solve. So things like :

```
if (starColour.red > 200 && starColour.blue > 200 && starColour.green > 200){
   doSomething();
}
```

look nice, but could be quite meaningless in the context of what the program is actually doing. I'd rather have it like this:

```
// we do this according to the requirement #xxxx blah-blah..
if (starColour.red > 200 && starColour.blue > 200 && starColour.green > 200){
   doSomething();
}
```

Comment: I agree: comments should describe what is done and why. If you need to describe how it's done, then you need to refactor your code.

Comment: You usually can turn your comment into a function name something like:

    if (starColourIsGreaterThanThreshold(){
        doSomething();
    }

    private boolean starColourIsGreaterThanThreshold() {
        return starColour.red > THRESHOLD && 
               starColour.blue > THRESHOLD && 
               starColour.green > THRESHOLD
    }

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/784250/is-it-possible-to-write-good-and-understandable-code-without-any-comments/803839#803839

Answer (score 7):

Well written code might eliminate the need for comments to explain what you're doing, but you'll still want comments to explain the why.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to then you would need to be very detailed in your variable names and methods names.

But in my opinion, there is no good way to do this. Comments serve a serious purpose in coding, even if you are the only one coding you still sometimes need to be reminded what part of the code you're looking at.

Comment: I agree - comments are an important part of coding.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can write code that doesn't need comments to describe what it does, but that may not be enough.

Just because a function is very clear in explaining what it does, does not, by itself, tell you why it is doing what it does.

As in everything, moderation is a good idea. Write code that is explanatory, and write comments that explain why it is there or what assumptions are being made.

Answer (score 2):

I think that the concept of [Fluent Interfaces](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface) is really a good example of this.

var bob = DB.GetCustomers().FromCountry("USA").WithName("Bob")

Comment: This adds a lot of coupling to your projet. If Customers from GetCustomers changes FromCountry(), then this code, located in a 3rd place will also fail. Minimizing impact of changes is crucial

Comment: @Eric, I can see your argument, but many frameworks are using this technique and the question is related to readability not coupling so I still think its a good example.

Answer (score 2):

[Clean Code](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132350882) by Robert C. Martin contains everything you need to write clean, understandable code.

Answer (score 1):

Use descriptive variable names and descriptive method names.   Use whitespace.

Make your code read like normal conversation.

Contrast the use of Matchers in Junit:

```
assertThat(x, is(3));
assertThat(x, is(not(4)));
assertThat(responseString, either(containsString("color")).or(containsString("colour")));
assertThat(myList, hasItem("3"));
```

with the traditional style of assertEquals:

```
assertEquals(3, x);
```

When I look at the `assertEquals` statement, it is not clear which parameter is "expected" and which is "actual".

When I look at `assertThat(x, is(3))` I can read that in English as "Assert that x is 3" which is very clear to me.

Another key to writing self-documenting code is to wrap any bit of logic that is not clear in a method call with a clear name.

```
if( (x < 3 || x > 17) && (y < 8 || y > 15) )
```

becomes

```
if( xAndYAreValid( x, y ) )  // or similar...
```

Comment: I was with you up until xAndYAreValidForOperationJ22. It doesn't make sense to give your methods such long and verbose names just to reference some operation ambiguously named "J22." Something like areValidCoordinates(x,y) or areWithinBounds(x,y) makes much more sense.

Comment: Also, the last two pieces of code seem like counterexamples for self-documenting code. You're unnecessarily obfuscating a very simple if() expression when a simple comment could both, show the comparisons being performed and state the author's intent. Instead, you're making the reader look up another function to see what is going on.

Comment: Fair point.   I was attempting to imply that there was some business logic with a name of "J22" that would be clear to other readers in the fictitious domain.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure writing code that is so expressive that you don't need comments is necessarily a great goal. Seems to me like another form of overoptimization. If I were on your team, I'd be pleased to see clear, concise code with just enough comments.

Answer (score 1):

In most cases, yes, you can write code that is clear enough that comments become unnecessary noise.

The biggest problem with comments is there is no way to check their accuracy. I tend to agree with Uncle Bob Martin in chapter 4 of his book, *Clean Code*:

> The proper use of comments is to compensate for our failure to express ourself in
>   code. Note that I used the word failure. I meant it. Comments are always failures. We must
>   have them because we cannot always figure out how to express ourselves without them,
>   but their use is not a cause for celebration.
>
> So when you find yourself in a position where you need to write a comment, think it
>   through and see whether there isn’t some way to turn the tables and express yourself in
>   code. Every time you express yourself in code, you should pat yourself on the back. Every
>   time you write a comment, you should grimace and feel the failure of your ability of
>   expression.

Most comments are either needless redundancy, outright fallacy or a crutch used to explain poorly written code. I say **most** because there are certain scenarios where the lack of expressiveness lies with the language rather than the programmer.

For instance the copyright and license information typically found at the beginning of a source file. As far as I'm aware no known construct exists for this in any of the popular languages. Since a simple one or two line comment suffices, its unlikely that such a construct will be added.

The original need for most comments has been replaced over time by better technology or practices. Using a change journal or commenting out code has been supplanted with source control systems. Explanatory comments in long functions can be mitigated by simply writing shorter functions. etc.

Comment: Clean code cannot express reasons as well as comments can.  Think of algorithmic selection and business rules like you think of copyrights.  Frequently an overall description is useful.  That being said, if a comment can disagree directly with the code, get rid of it.

Comment: *"Every time you write a comment, you should grimace and feel the failure of your ability of expression."* Ouch!  So much opinionated should-ing and guilt-tripping in that excerpt!  Thinking too hard and worrying about every little detail can really bog me down.  I have to find a balance.  In general I agree with him but I wish he would explain things in terms of how well they fulfill programmers' needs rather than such black-and-white terms.

Answer (score 1):

You usually can turn your comment into a function name something like:

```
if (starColourIsGreaterThanThreshold(){
    doSomething(); 
}

....

private boolean starColourIsGreaterThanThreshold() { 
    return starColour.red > THRESHOLD && 
           starColour.blue > THRESHOLD && 
           starColour.green > THRESHOLD
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think comments should express the why, perhaps the what, but as much as possible the code should define the how (the behavior).

Someone should be able to read the code and understand what it does (the how) from the code. What may not be obvious is why you would want such behavior and what this behavior contributes to the overall requirements.

The need to comment should give you pause, though. Maybe how you are doing it is too complicated and the need to write a comment shows that.

There is a third alternative to documenting code - logging. A method that is well peppered with logging statements can do a lot to explain the why, can touch on the what and may give you a more useful artifact than well named methods and variables regarding the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code entirely without comments and still have your code be followable, then you'll have to write a larger number of shorter methods.  Methods will have to have descriptive names.  Variables will also have to have descriptive names.  One common method of doing this is to give variables the name of nouns and to give methods the names of verbal phrases.  For example:

```
account.updateBalance();
child.givePacifier();
int count = question.getAnswerCount();
```

Use `enum`s liberally.  With an `enum`, you can replace most `boolean`s and integral constants.  For example:

```
public void dumpStackPretty(boolean allThreads) {
    ....
}

public void someMethod() {
    dumpStackPretty(true);
}
```

vs

```
public enum WhichThreads { All, NonDaemon, None; }
public void dumpStackPretty(WhichThreads whichThreads) {
    ....
}

public void someMethod() {
    dumpStackPretty(WhichThreads.All);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Descriptive names is your obvious first bet.

Secondly make sure each method does one thing and only one thing. If you have a public method that needs to do many things, split it up into several private methods and call those from the public method, in a way that makes the logic obvious.

Some time ago I had to create a method that calculated the correlation of two time series.

To calculate the correlation you also need the mean and standard deviation. So I had two private methods (well actually in this case they were public as they could be used for other purposes (but assuming they couldn't then they would be private)) for calculating A) the mean, B) the standard deviation.

This sort of splitting up of function into the smallest part that makes sense is probably the most important thing to make a code readable.

How do you decide where to break up methods. My way is, if the name is obvious e.g. getAddressFromPage it is the right size. If you have several contenders you are probably trying to do too much, if you can't think of a name that makes sense you method may not "do" enough - although the latter is much less likely.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really think comments are a good idea in most cases. Comments don't get checked by the compiler so they so often are misleading or wrong as the code changes over time.  Instead, I prefer self documenting, concise methods that don't need comments. It can be done, and I have been doing it this way for years.

Writing code without comments takes practice and discipline, but I find that the discipline pays off as the code evolves.

Answer (score 0):

It may not be comments, but, to help someone better understand what it going on you may need some diagrams explaining how the program should work, as, if a person knows the big picture then it is easier to understand code.

But, if you are doing something complex then you may need some comments, for example, in a very math intensive program.

The other place I find comments useful and important, is to ensure that someone doesn't replace code with something that looks like it should work, but won't.  In that case I leave the bad code in, and comment it out, with an explanation as to why it shouldn't be used.

So, it is possible to write code without comments, but only if you are limited in what types of applications you are writing, unless you can explain why a decision was made, somewhere, and not call it a comment.

For example, a random generator can be written many ways. If you pick a particular implementation it may be necessary to explain why you picked that particular generator, as the period may be sufficiently long for current requirements, but later the requirements may change and your generator may not be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's possible, if you consider the fact that **not everybody likes the same style. So in order to minimize comments, knowing your "readers" is the most important thing.**

In "information systems" kind-of software, try using declarative sentence, try to approximate the code line to a line in english, and avoid "mathematical programming" (with the i,j and k for index, and the one-liners-to-do-a-lot) at all costs.

Answer (score 0):

I think code can be self-documenting to a large degree, and I think it's crucial, but reading even well-written code can be like looking at cells of the human body with a microscope.  It sometimes takes comments to really explain the big picture of how pieces of the system fit together, especially if it solves a really complex and difficult problem.

Think about special data structures.  If all that computer scientists had ever published about data structures were well-written code, few would really understand the relative benefit of one data structure over another -- because Big-O runtime of any given operation is sometimes just not obvious from reading the code.  That's where the math and amortized analysis presented in articles come in.